# How to get IP for various geolocations

Tags: geolocation, ip

We've now allowed the usage of special characters, but that is giving error if the geolocation name is having one in it. The geolocation is being read by the payment gateway based on the IP.

I'm aware that we can add the query/command at the end of the payment URL to simulate the payment being done from another geolocation. But the barrier is to get the IPs for respective geoloactions.

How might I know the IP's for different geolocations to trick the (test)payment-gateway to think that I'm doing payment from some other geolocation?

PS: Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: About what programming language is this about?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'm with the outsourced testing team for this project and dev is also not sure about how to get the IP of the geolocations to test.
I hope I chose the correct site for asking the question.

Comment: I also have no idea, but you can leave this question here, maybe someone will notice it :) @JohnShepard

Comment: A man will leave the question and hope for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

For developer testing, you can always use VPN to test the API call from different locations.

Opera Developer Edition is providing free VPN server now.

Comment: We could try VPN, but if I'm thinking correctly we will get a limited number of options in that since we cannot control from which geolocation the VPN is routing our traffic. That again binds our hands.